# preg_match_all - regex expression help

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've been given the following regex expression:

```
 if (preg_match_all("'(http://)?(www[.])?(youtube|vimeo)[^\s]+'is",$prova,$n))
 {
     foreach ($n[3] as $key => $site)
     {
         $video_links[$site][] = $n[0][$key];
     }
```

However, if I have a string like:

> "hello, look at my **vimeo** video here:
>   http://www.vimeo.com..../ very nice hm?"

Instead of receiving only the url, I'm getting ALSO the word vimeo.

I believe the regex expression is retring more then it should and I would like to retrive ONLY the urls that it finds, not every reference of "vimeo" or "youtube".

Can I request your help in order to narrow the scope of this expression, so that only the URLs are retrieved ?

Comment: Try changing the `[^\s]+` to `\S+` (capital `S`, which means everything but white-space...

Comment: I don't want to attempt to answer this(as several people have already), but I would like to provide a great site for testing RegEx: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - it's helped me MANY times!

Comment: @s992 - it goes directly to my favourites. Thanks for sharing it. I will try it out more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code can help out a bit:

```
<?php
    //Test string
    $prova = "\"hello, look at my <strong>vimeo</strong> video here:  <a href=\"http://www.vimeo.com..../\" rel=\"nofollow\">http://www.vimeo.com..../</a> very nice hm?\"";
    $prova .= " vimeo vimeo.com/something?id=somethingcrazy&testing=true  ";
    //if we match then capture all matches
    if (preg_match_all("'(http://)?(www\.)?(youtube|vimeo)\.([a-z0-9_/?&+=.]+)'is",$prova,$n)){
        foreach ($n[0] as $key => $site){
            //for each match that matched the whole pattern
            //save the match as a site
            $video_links[$site][] = $n[0][$key];
        }
    }
    //display results
    print_r($video_links);
?>
```

This will not match the word vimeo.  It will match vimeo.com/something?id=somethingcrazy&testing=true and it will match http://www.vimeo.com..../ twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just change $n[0] on foreach argument to $n[3]. So that I can get either youtube or vimeo. PS - If I need to add a third one but within a subdomain, not youtube nor vimeo but, let's say: video.frog.es should the regex expression be: "'(http://)?(www\.)?(youtube|vimeo|video\.frog\.)\.([a-z0-9_/?&+=.]+)'is"  ??

Comment: Assuming a video.frog.es link looks like this: http://video.frog.es/somevid or video.frog.es/vid It would need to be "'(http://)?(www\.)?(youtube|vimeo|video\.frog)\.([a-z0-9_/?&+=.]+)'is"  Your above regex is very similar but you are looking for one too many dots after frog.

Comment: Thank you. I see that with my tried expression I would allow video.frog..es as well, witch is, incorrect. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

First question mark `?` in the regex is unneeded. It makes the preceeding search strings optional, thus also match the bare `vimeo` word in texts. Try:

```
preg_match_all("'(http://)(www[.])?(youtube|vimeo)[.][^\s]+'is",
```

Tip: add `(?<![,.)])` at the end if you want to exclude typical interpunction that often screws up such url searches.

---

As alternative, with http:// and www. optional, but depending on presence of a path:

```
preg_match_all("'(http://|www[.])*(youtube|vimeo)[.]\w+/[^\s]+'is",
```

Comment: @mario: Also, `[.]` is unnecessary. `.` would do. It was probably meant to be escaped as well (`\.`). I think you should change that to `(www\.)?` since the subdomain is optional.

Comment: @netcoder: I also do that often. Somehow `[.]` seems nicer than `\.` - But the www. should indeed be optional.

Comment: @mario: but a lot of times people will paste urls without the `http://`, so that part being optional *might* be wanted...

Comment: @ircmaxell: It's not really an url then. But if that's expected content than a wacky `(http://|www[.])+` would cover it.

Comment: @mario - indeed either with http:// or without http:// both, will be the case. Users tend to forget those things and I need to take that into consideration. Do you care to provide a full expression containing that option as well ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MEM: See edit. Made it dependend on a path, since you probably don't want plain "www.youtube.com" links without video parameters anyway. But look at TheDogs answer; looks very workable too.